.NET Core 3.1: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
I am working on a .net core web app code challenge and I am getting the following error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target
machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The code is in this repo
The error is occurring in this method:
public async Task<TeamDTO> AddTeam(string teamName)
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var team = new TeamDTO { Name = teamName };
    var response = await client.PostAsync("teams", new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(team), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TeamDTO>(responseBody, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
}

On this line of code:
var response = await client.PostAsync("teams", new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(team), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

I am trying to connect to this API method:
    [HttpPost("Post")]
    public virtual ActionResult<GameDTO> Post(GameDTO gameDTO)
    {
        var game = new Game
        {
            HomeTeamId = gameDTO.HomeTeamId,
            AwayTeamId = gameDTO.AwayTeamId,
            Date = gameDTO.Date,
            WinningTeamId = gameDTO.WinningTeamId
        };
        game.Id = Repository.Insert(game);

        return Ok(gameDTO);
    }

I am running VS 2022 on Windows 11 pro. I am using IIS Express and launching both applications from the same VS 2022 solution.  I have thoroughly tested (there are unit tests) the API code and it works. The API and the web app both launch.  Everything works fine until I click Add Team in the games view of the web app, then the code shown above is hit etc. I believe this is a configuration issue.

What's "teams?"

The TeamsController.

check your base url

"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ApiSettings": {
"BaseUri": "http://localhost:5000/"
},
_baseUri = configuration["ApiSettings:BaseUri"];

is service is running in 5000 port ?

This is where it gets interesting, the web api app is running on http://localhost:20269/api/home in IIS Express but there is a handoff to Kestrel at http://localhost:5000.

I have 2 start apps configured to run in iis express.  Both apps launch and run in debug mode.  The api code in the repo works.  The web app launches and works until I attempt to add a team, then the connection to the web api is refused.

replace here "await client.PostAsync("teams", new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(team), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));"
to be
await client.PostAsync("Post", new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(team), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
And try

replace here "await client.PostAsync("teams",
to be
await client.PostAsync("Post",
or
await client.PostAsync("api/Post",

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


I am using IIS Express and launching both applications from the same
VS 2022 solution. I have thoroughly tested (there are unit tests) the
API code and it works. The API and the web app both launch

You said you are using IIS Express ,but port of the base uri  doesn't match;
"ApiSettings": { "BaseUri": "localhost:5000" },

 _baseUri = configuration["ApiSettings:BaseUri"];

modify 5000 to the port of your api project(20269) when you run it in IIS Express
